# Multiple Columns in Case using joins

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table "payments" and "payments1". There is a join on both the tables.

```
Payments:
-----------
id  type  amount values
1    A     10     x
2    B     20     y
2    A     30     z
```

I am trying to group by id and type. Such that I can get the results as

```
id   type  total_amount type1 total_amount(sum)
-----------------------------------------------
1     A      10                             
2     A      20           B       30
```

I have tried following query

```
select 
case when r.type = 'A' then @payment+sum(r.amount) end  as total_amount,
case when r.type = 'B' then @refund+sum(r.amount) end as total_amount(sum)
from payments r
```

But in CASE it gets executed only for one type?

Comment: Question is unclear. Please list your tables properly

Comment: Table is listed as payments.Assuming we can use joins also was the question

Comment: Where is second table(payments1)? Try using left join

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear but I assume you're looking for the group by statement.

```
select 
case when r.type = 'A' then @payment+sum(r.amount) end  as total_amount,
case when r.type = 'B' then @refund+sum(r.amount) end as total_amount(sum)
FROM payments r
GROUP BY r.type
```

for each distinct r.type value in the table there will be result row with the aggregation date in the select statement.

Also a different suggestion:

```
select 
(case r.type when 'A' then @payment else @refund end)+sum(r.amount) as total_amount
FROM payments r
GROUP BY r.type
```

Answer (score 0):

If types are fixed, think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  'A' as type,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type='A' THEN amount END) sum_typeA,
  'B' as type1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type='B' THEN amount END) sum_typeB
FROM
  Payments
GROUP BY
  id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6d8ac).